# Get events from polyline or marker from a DirectionsRenderer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the DirectionsService and the route method to generate a DirectionsResult. I'm also using the DirectionsRenderer object to display results because it's very easy to use. I've no problem detecting directions_changed events, but I would like to know if it's possible do get events from the polyline representing the itinerary, or even, events from markers (small circles) generated after dragging the polyline.

When using google maps (maps.google.com, "Get Directions"), you can drag the polyline, right click on it (or on markers), this has the effect to display a menu. So I guess there is a way to catch events from DirectionsRenderer (supposing Google use this object in that case).

If anybody got an idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm also seeking answer for your question. Until then, I'll try to figure it out myself and I'll post back if I find something useful.

Update: after a few minutes in JavaScript, I found out that the **DirectionsResult** object holds an array of waypoints, including the ones created when the path is dragged with the cursor. If you completed the [Draggable Directions tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#DraggableDirections) you can access that object via directionsDisplay.directions, inside the callback method for the **directions_changed** event. That object holds a member named **sf** which holds a **waypoints** array if there are any, if not, it's null. Each member of this array contains a member named **location**, storing the coordinates under **wa** (latitude) and **ya** (longitude).

To demonstrate the waypoint handling, I wrote a little function which displays markers in the place of waypoints. In order to test it, add the following global variable to the script;

```
var markers = [];
```

modify the **directions_changed** event callback function

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {  
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.directions);  
});
```

to the following;

```
google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplay, 'directions_changed', function() {  
    computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.directions);  
    displayWaypoints(directionsDisplay.directions);  
});
```

and add this function too

```
function displayWaypoints(result) {  
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i) {  
        markers[i].setMap(null);  
    }  
    markers = [];  
    if (result.sf.waypoints) {  
            for (var i = 0; i < result.sf.waypoints.length; ++i) {  
                    var latitude = result.sf.waypoints[i].location.wa;  
                    var longitude = result.sf.waypoints[i].location.ya;    
                    markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({  
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),  
                            map: map  
                    }));  
            }  
    }  
}
```

You might also want to suppress the built-in marker drawing of DirectionsRenderer. 
Replace

```
var rendererOptions = {  
    draggable: true  
};
```

with the following

```
var rendererOptions = {  
    draggable: true,  
    suppressMarkers: true  
};
```

I couldn't find any official references to that **sf** member. Use it at your own risk, Google may modify the API without further notice. Until they make a public API for manipulating waypoints after the directions have been dragged, I can't think of a better solution.

This is my first Stack Overflow answer, I hope that I was helpful.

Kind regards,
Johnny

Comment: Well done Johnny, that's exactly what I expected! I also tried to find such special property on result object. Could you tell me how did you find it ? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I use Chrome, hit right click and Inspect Element. I just wrote directionsDisplay in the JS console and that way I could analyse that DirectionsRenderer object, see its member, etc.

Comment: It seems that Google has already changed the API. It's not working any more and I have barely any spare time to look into the new location of the waypoints' coordinates. Sorry :(

Comment: The new location is at $f instead of sf. You can track the object by using console.log(variable) in chrome and checking your console.

Comment: @Johnny: Yeah, it's generally a good idea not to use undocumented parts of the API, especially the ones that are probably named according to the whims of their code minification engine. I would expect any minor update to the API, even if it didn't touch the directions code, to break this method.

Comment: waypoints are also accessible via the result.getDirections().routes[0].legs object array. Looping through this array, you can extrapolate the waypoints from the start_location and end_location objects of each leg.

Comment: Yes, the exact [(and documented)](http://code.google.com/intl/pl/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsLeg) property is called `via_waypoints`. With that property used instead of undocumented (and in today's version named `Zf`) one, Johnny's answer is perfect.